# Fit-content width for columns in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code here:

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  padding: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  background: skyblue;
  margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
  padding: 1%;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item">Really really really really really really long</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is some blank space in front of the second and the third columns.

Is there any way to get rid of that?

---

Edit: Here is the produced result (Chrome 84):
[image: Produced result]

What I hope to see:
[image: Need]

Comment: what is meaning `get rid of that`? make it more clear.

Comment: @jinongun Sorry, I was referring to the blank space in front of the columns.

Comment: you should better show the blueprint that you want.

Comment: it is not entirely clear what free space you are talking about. can you show a screenshot of the problem area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does adding `align-content: flex-end;` to `#container` do what you want?

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  padding: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  background: skyblue;
  margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
  padding: 1%;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item">Really really really really really really long</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
    <div class="item">Short</div>
  </div>
</div>
```